# My points have been decreased without any notice?

Tags: support, reputation

My reputation was 572 yesterday which is now 372 it was decreased without any reason why is this so. A decrease of 200 is insane.
https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow/2015-12-27/3078037#3078037

Comment: Did you notice the 1-day 200 point *increase*? Did you read the page http://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed which was recommended in your Reputation overview?

Comment: Funny, I must have missed that meta post where you complained that an increase of nearly 200 in 20 minutes is *insane*.

Answer (score 15):

[image]

Yesterday, someone voted for your posts multiple times in quick succession. This is called serial voting - the user seemed to be voting for *you*, not your posts. This isn't allowed here.

Today, the system [automatically reverted it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed)

Comment: And another 106 reverted since then.

Answer (score 6):

You were informed, though not with an explicit notification. [Look at your reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3078037/syed-tayyab-abbas?tab=reputation). You lost 190 rep due to [serial upvotes being removed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed).